# JS Function works with individual arrays but misbehaves when trying to loop through an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to solve a problem where I am required to loop through an array of arrays, each of which contains a list of numbers that together make up a credit card number. I've been asked to use the Luhn algorithm to validate these numbers, working from the rightmost number in each array to the leftmost. I came up with a function that successfully returns true or false for each array correctly (I know in advance that 5 are valid and 5 are false while a remaining 5 are not known). However, when I then try to loop through the array containing all these arrays, calling the function on them each in turn, the program hangs for ages and finally returns a long list of trues, far longer than the 15 results I expect. My code is below, validateCred seems to work for each card number individually, but findValidCards does not. I can't see why this is happening, can anyone enlighten me?

```js
const validateCred = arr => {
  const resultArray = [];
  let index = (arr.length) - 1;
  if ((index % 2) != 0) {
    for (i = index; i >= 0; i--) {
      if ((i % 2) == 0) {
        let doubled = arr[i] * 2;
        if (doubled > 9) {
          let numToUnshift = doubled - 9;
          resultArray.unshift(numToUnshift);
        } else {
          resultArray.unshift(doubled);
        };
      } else {
        resultArray.unshift(arr[i]);
      };
    };
  } else {
    for (i = index; i >= 0; i--) {
      if ((i % 2) != 0) {
        let doubled = arr[i] * 2;
        if (doubled > 9) {
          let numToUnshift = doubled - 9;
          resultArray.unshift(numToUnshift);
        } else {
          resultArray.unshift(doubled);
        };
      } else {
        resultArray.unshift(arr[i]);
      };
    };
  };

  const reducer = (acc, curr) => acc + curr;
  let sum = resultArray.reduce(reducer);

  if ((sum % 10) == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  };
}

const findInvalidCards = array => {
  let resultArray = [];
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let card = array[i];
    let result = validateCred(card);
    console.log(result);
  };
};
```

Comment: You have some test data? Which function is the function that accepts the array of arrays?

Comment: Declare your variables (with `var` or `let` or `const` as appropriate). Variables default to being global in JavaScript. Currently the `i` in `findInvalidCards()` is the same variable as the `i` in the other function, so they step on each other.

Comment: Nothing to do with your question or its answer, but a kitten cries every time someone writes `if (condition) return true; else return false;` Just use `return condition;`

Comment: findValidCards accepts the array of arrays

Comment: Pointy - I corrected not declaring index properly but it didn't help. Will edit post

Comment: Pointy again - You were right about the second i, changed it to j and code worked as expected. Can you add as answer so I can accept?